# Zoom jPanel using JSlider in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming, jslider

I want to zoom a Jpanel using a slider.
I have some circles drown into my jpanel (I will code them to move later) 
the problem I have is the zoom button, I already used the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/15962432/3080016
but it's not exactly what I want.
I'm using netbeans gui builder please help me and thanks :)

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package javaapplication13;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel(){
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                super.paintComponent(g);
                int w =getWidth(); // real width of canvas
                int h =getHeight(); // real height of canvas
                // Translate used to make sure scale is centered
                g2.translate(w/2, h/2);
                g2.scale((double)jSlider1.getValue(),(double)jSlider1.getValue());
                g2.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
                g2.fillOval(200, 200, 25, 25);
                g2.fillOval(200, 223, 25, 25);
                g2.fillOval(150, 223, 25, 25);
                g2.fillOval(100, 200, 25, 25);

                //repaint(); too much cpu use.
            }
        };

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSlider1.setMinimum(1);
        jSlider1.setValue(1);
        jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSlider1StateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((jSlider1.getValue()*5),(jSlider1.getValue()*10)));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 317, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
jPanel1.repaint();
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this in...  it's not refreshing cause you haven't asked it to.

```
    jSlider1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            jPanel1.repaint();
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes I know but the zoom work only if the jframe is in default size other than that there is no zoom just a blank panel.

Comment: the zoom is working at any size, but if you're not seeing your ovals, it means they've zoomed off the screen.

Comment: If you get rid of g2.translate(w/2, h/2); and g2.translate(-w/2, -h/2);  you can maximize and see what I mean...

Comment: yeah you right but I don't know why I added a jscrollpane and it don't appears while zooming. could you please help me and sorry

Comment: Hmm, well a JScrollPane is for Swing.  Your Graphics2D object is AWT, so Swing is not going to care about it, or know when it gets bigger. The JScrollPane will only react if the JPanel gets bigger.  So try add in jPanel1.setSize or setPreferredSize in the jSlider's changeListener too, perhaps?  Or maybe you can set the jPanel's size in the paintComponent code itself?

Comment: okay thank you so much for the answer I didn't know Graphics 2D objet are AWT and not swing good information thank you ! :)